# Powershell program doesn't work fine from .bat file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to run a powershell script from .bat file. The script name is `MailSystemWatcher.ps1`. I save it here C:\Users\AL0447842\Desktop\Scripts_Mails_en_local_Domino\En_cours_DFCI_Mail_Script\MailSystemWatcher.ps1

The purpose of the script is to watch a directory for new files event. When i add new files in the directory, i rename them.

`MailSystemWatcher.ps1` works fine when i run it in powershell editor, the files are renamed but when i try to run it from .bat file the files are not renamed.
This is the content of the .bat :

```
@ECHO OFF

PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -noexit -Command "& {Start-Process 
PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File 
""C:\Users\AL0447842\Desktop\Scripts_Mails_en_local_Domino\En_cours_DFCI_Mail_Script\MailSystemWatcher.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
pause
```

It seems like it runs well, cmd window is displayed with no erros, i also see the same print in powershell output pane, compared to when i run it directly without .bat file.
I think i'm missing something with .bat file, i also try to run it with admin priviledges but no changes.

Comment: It seems redundant to call powershell to call powershell to run a file. Why not just reduce that to a single call

Comment: I will have to add more powershell script to be executed to .bat file. I'm just making test with just one

Comment: do test this `powershell -noexit "& ""c:\1.ps1"""` ?

Comment: I already try this @Hidd3n. No changes, the files still not be renamed. I am starting to despair

Comment: `powershell -noexit "& ""c:\1.ps1"""` is sample not exactly code i check this again and working perfectly , I doubtful to execution policy for powershell script check 32 bit and 64 bit powershell you should run `Set-ExecutionPolicy -bypass` 64 bit in"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0" and 32 bit in "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0"

Comment: Thanks for the help @SoheilH, i try this but don't work. It is really weird. The system is 64 bit, this is the cmd i use : `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass  "& ""C:\Users\AL0447842\Desktop\Scripts_Mails_en_local_Domino\En_cours_DFCI_Mail_Script\MailSystemWatcher.ps1"""`

Comment: do U check 32 bit or not ?

Comment: Yes the system is 64 but i try with 32 bit cmd too. I think i get my error. I'm too stupid. If i launch with a .bat like i'm doing here, when the .bat will end, the powershell script, will be killed. That can explain why i'm still getting no changes when i drop my file in the directory. Correct me if i'm wrong and sorry for my english.